# Giving help on an off-topic question

Tags: discussion, scope

I encountered a few of those questions. basically, a lost soul is looking for a starting point to make their dream project a reality, and naturally, when they Google anything programming related, they end up on SO and ask "What's the best library/framework for X", or "How would you do `<insert more or less convoluted idea here>`". The example that prompted this question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952151/best-setup-for-very-simple-single-page-app.

While I totally agree that those questions are off-topic, I always try to give the user a pointer or two in a comment before casting my VTC; maybe a keyword, or a bit of advice. I make sure to do it only on the very new questions, in the hope that the user will see it before the hammer hits. I also do it only when I feel the user has spent a bit of time on his post, at least grammar-checked and made it polite. Most of those questions are broad as hell, and I totally empathize with the user who has no idea where to start, so it's not about giving a definitive answer, just a bit of help/hope. We've all started somewhere!

I realize that by doing that, I may be contributing to enabling those off-topic questions, but at the same time I feel like it's in the spirit of the site to help others, so... I'm not really sure what my question is, I guess it's about best practices and how not to alienate newbies, while keeping the site clean?

Comment: damn, you're right, I looked for a dupe, and couldn't find one :p

Comment: Meh, I do the same thing. There's nothing wrong with giving a clearly benign (new) asker a pointer to a good Google search along with the close vote.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Judging by the answers on the dupe question, I guess we're both wrong... kinda ironic though, for a place dedicated to welcoming and helping people

Comment: Well, we never said we were dedicated to helping *everyone* in *every* situation. As general advice, the answers in the duplicate aren't wrong. But as said, if you feel an asker is clearly benign and new, I don't see the harm in helping them help themselves. There's a huge difference between giving a pointer, and a complete answer they can use/copy&paste right away.

Comment: exactly, and by not ostracizing them at the start of their journey, they'll most probbly come back to SO with real questions once they get started. As I said, it's not about the low-quality posts bordering on disrespect of those looking for a quick copypaste. Those are future users!

Comment: I agree with @Pekka웃 -- for me, it ultimately boils down to a judgement call based on how blatantly off-topic is the question, as well as on how lazy is the asker. Given how common lazy and blatantly off-topic questions are, not giving advice is a sensible default, but I'd say there is no real harm in overriding it in the more "benign" cases.